# How i make my website look good on smartphones?

Tags: css

So im building this onepage type site. I've made it from 0 and now i tried to check how it gonna look on smartphones. The site is only like 50% wide and the rest is like blank page. 
I was looking for the reasons but i have no idea what happened. I am pretty new to this, its my first webpage tbh. I dont rly know where should i start seeking for help so i came here.

Comment: First at all you should read about media queries. It's simple article with good explanation  https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

All your design is static. You have to make it dynamic with the view of the display. You can use bootstrap grid system to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilities :

1. You can use Bootstrap to make a responsive website : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/
2. If you don't want to use Bootstrap, you can use `@media queries` to adapt the design depending the screen size. You can refer to https://media-queries.aliasdmc.fr/media-queries-live.php to check what you can use. For example, if you want apply modifications only on landscape smartphone, you need to use the following code on your css :

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
  /* Here your code */
}
```